# How to setup docker-compose, pytest, Selenium Driver and geckodriver/chromedriver correctly

Tags: django, docker, selenium-webdriver, pytest, geckodriver

I am testing my django app with pytest. Now I want to use Selenium for system tests. I am also using docker so to execute my tests I do `docker-compose -f local.yml run django pytest`

When I try to use Selenium I get the message that `'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`.

I read many questions here on SO and I followed the instructions. Yet, I think my path can't be found because I am executing everything in a docker-container. Or am I mistaken?

I added the geckodriver path to my bash-profile by checking my path with: 
`which geckodriver`. The result of this is:`/usr/local/bin/geckodriver`
Then I added this to my profile and when I type `echo $PATH` I can see this: `/usr/local/bin/geckodriver/bin:`. So I assume all is set correctly. I also tried setting it manually doing: 
`self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')`

Since I still get the error I assume it has sth to do with docker. That's why my specific question is: How can I setup the PATH for geckodriver with pytes, selenium and docker-compose?

Any help or hint into the right direction is very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Here is my docker-compose file as requested:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

When I am debugging by doing

```
for p in sys.path:
            print(p)
```

I get:

```
usr/local/bin
/usr/local/lib/python36.zip
/usr/local/lib/python3.6
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

So my geckodriver is not there I assume?

Comment: Please share you docker-compose file. You should setup `$PATH` for docker container running Selenium, docker's host `$PATH` is not inherited to containers.

Comment: Thanks leopal. I added the file

Comment: also trying to debug I got some path outputs which I also added

Comment: I added this to my docker-compose file but without success: ```ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver/bin:${PATH}"```

Comment: Is there any other way I can set my PATH variable here in my file?

Comment: When I set it like this: ```ENV PATH "$PATH:/usr/local/bin/geckodriver/bin:"```
and build my images anew it tells me ```No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver':``` . But the directory does indeed exist

Comment: nobody has an idea?